# Transcribing testimonial

Tags: 1920s, london, transcriptions

I am attempting to transcribe a testimonial for a grandaunt of my wife:

[image]

So far, I have come up with the following:

```
University of London
Courtauld Institute of Art
20 Portman Square, London, W.I.
Welbeck 1388-9
(2 lines)
                                            July 13th 
                                                1927
```

> I have pleasure in stating that Miss Rees has taken a years course of
> lectures in Art History and covered the development of architecture,
> painting of sculpture as a background to the history of culture. She
> has shown ??? interest in the course and done a monthly essay
> throughout the year. Her written work has shown a capacity to respond
> to the ascetic appeal of ??? of  art as well as the power to analyse
> its formal aspects. I feel sure that she should be able to convey a
> feeling for colour and design to others in teaching craft work.

```
        Helen Low????
        B. A. ??? Diploma of ???
        Courtauld Institure
```

I think I have most of it right but there are some words I am unsure of.

---

I can't workout how to display the transcribed text with better formatting  in my question - it either shows all scrunched up or with loads of blank lines in between.

Comment: In order, I think your missing words are - 'keen'; 'a work'; 'Lowenthal' (?); 'Lond' (abbreviation for 'London'); 'the'

Comment: FYI, you may want to share this with the Courtauld and/or the University. The [University of London](https://london.ac.uk/ways-study/study-campus-london/member-institutions/courtauld-institute-art) says the Courtauld was founded in 1932, while the [Courtauld](https://courtauld.ac.uk/about-us/) itself says it was founded in the 1930s. They might appreciate this piece of history.

Comment: @shoover I have just sent an email to both places. Let us see what they say!

Comment: ascetic => aesthetic

Comment: @shoover I had a reply from University of London. All they said was: "Thank you for sending us this. We will be in touch if we have any questions regarding this. "

Answer (score 3):

The signer of the letter is probably:

> Helen Olga Lowenthal, educator: born Belfast 21 June 1904; co-founder,
> Attingham Summer School Trust 1951; Course Director, Attingham Summer
> School 1952-76; Education Officer, Victoria and Albert Museum 1953-69;
> first Vice-President of the National Association of Decorative and
> Fine Art Societies, 1967; OBE 1970; died London 30 March 1993.

https://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/obituary-helen-lowenthal-1455378.html .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think:

> She has shown ??? interest

should be:

> She has shown keen interest

Comment: Thanks. That was suggested in the comments and does make sense.